# How can I execute the next sentence until the last(include listener) is done in Android

Tags: android, dialog

```
showPasswordDialog(context);
mFoundPassword = true;
return errorcode;
```

The above two sentences are in my code, and showPasswordDialog has an listener

```
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(
            new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        String passwordInput = editText.getText().toString();

                        int ndkErrorCode = mPdfRenderer.openDocument(mFileDescriptor, passwordInput);
                        if (ndkErrorCode == 0) {
                            Log.i(sClassTag, "Password is right!");
                            mPassword = passwordInput;

                              mTag = true;

                            return true;
                        } else {
                            Log.e(sClassTag, "Password is wrong!");
                            editText.setText("");
                           }
```

I want to when the password is right then the code will go to execute mFoundPassword = true; or it will block to wait for the right password input.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(
            new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        String passwordInput = editText.getText().toString();

                        int ndkErrorCode = mPdfRenderer.openDocument(mFileDescriptor, passwordInput);
                        if (ndkErrorCode == 0) {
                            Log.i(sClassTag, "Password is right!");
                            mPassword = passwordInput;
                            //// Added code here
                            mFoundPassword = true;
                              mTag = true;

                            return true;
                        } else {
                            Log.e(sClassTag, "Password is wrong!");
                            editText.setText("");
                           }
```

Comment: if I add the code in listener action it needs to be final, and I need to execute the return code after mFoundPassword = true;

Comment: Dont make `mFoundPassword` a local variable.

Comment: I see your meaning, if it is not local in  can be no final, but I still need to execute the return sentence below mFoundPassword, so I need to go to the right palce.

Comment: What code do you want to execute when the password is correct?

Comment: I need to execute the return in the edited question.